# Basic Java HiLow guessing game

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, nested-loops

I am fully aware this question has been asked many times, it is a classic first year problem in CSC. I am not looking for the solution to the problem itself. I *think* I have it basically done however I am missing something that I cannot find how to do.

Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class HiLow
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1,guess;
        int count = 0;
        num1 = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 or 100 or enter 0 at anytime to quit: ");
            guess = scan.nextInt();
            count++;
            if(guess == num1 || guess == 0) {
                if(guess == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Congrats you've guessed correct and your total guesses is " + count );
                break;
            }
            else if (guess > 100 || guess < 1) {
                System.out.print("I see you cannot follow instructions. I said ");
                count--;
            }
            else if (guess > num1) {
                System.out.println("You have guessed too high. ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You have guessed too low.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is i am required to prompt the user at the point of "if the user quits or successfully guesses the correct number, prompt the user to see if they wish to play again". I am lost and not sure how to continue my while loop from the beginning after my breaks. Is there a way to end the break condition i have from (guess == num1 || guess ==0) and direct my program to start again at the while(true) statement?

Thanks

Comment: A good learning exercise for you at this moment is to understand the difference between break and continue statements. Look them up and build a very simple example outside the current question. That will help you find the answer to this problem of yours.

Comment: Yep, went through my class notes, looked it up online and none of this actually answers my question of how to restart my while loop. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I will say search up `continue;`

Tips to help further:

1. The `continue` statement is used to bring the loop back to the start, try it instead of a `break` where you want the user to continue.
2. You need some sort of check **if** the user wants to continue, (try asking them to type in some specific int you check, p.s negative numbers are integers as well)

Answer (score 0):

@Ahmed thinks you should `continue`, I would rather not `break`, or conditionally `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are multiple ways you could accomplish this, One would be to just to prompt the user with a "press q to quit" dialogue using the Scanner class where .next() returns the String when the user hits enter:

```
  if(guess == num1 || guess == 0) {
            if(guess == 0) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Congrats you've guessed correct and your total guesses is " + count );
                
            }
            System.out.println("would you like to play again [y/n]?");
            if(scan.next().equals("y")){
              num1 = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
              count=0;
            }else{
              break;
            }
        }
```

If thats what you mean. Hopefully I helped.
or maybe you can have it only quit at zero, if so just remove that second break and replace it with num1 = generator.nextInt(100) + 1; to set the new value to guess.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about!

Comment: yeah was thinking to put some code down to help. Also, I don't understand. What is wrong with a break? Why not just break the loop conditionally, when the user puts n for example?

Comment: When the user chooses to play again, shouldn't you also reset variable `count`?

Comment: yes, you have to. Let me fix that.